# How do I trade Dream World items with my other cart?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I have two Pokémon game cartridges on the same Dream World account. Is it possible to trade or share items between them using the Dream World?

Comment: You can interchange the 2 games registered under the same Pokemon Global Link account, as they are treated as 2 separate Dream World accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm a little too late, but just in case: You can "add yourself" as a friend in the Dream World. That is, make a Dream Pal request from one game account to the other. That way you can easily access your other game's Dream World home, and swap items using the Share Shelf. I did it by trading between my games and then searching on the Dream Pal map for my Game Pals (there you can see the people with whom you've battled/traded). You can trade with yourself using the GTS in order to do that, if you only have one console.

Comment: That worked, after I did one thing: You have to go to https://www.pokemon.com/us/account/edit-profile/ and set your "Choose who can see your Game Pal and Dream Pal Rosters" to "Everyone". I had it on "Just Friends" and it greyed out everyone, even people I had traded with locally and online.

Comment: Oh, well, I think I always had it on "Everyone", so I didn't realize about that last bit. LOL